# Rails 3.1 javascript file usage

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I have a rails 3.1 app where I can create mail blasts.  I have a list of all my blasts with a mail link to mail a specific blast (using ajax).  I have a custom action in my blasts controller that I want to use.  When I click the link it wants to call show.js.coffee instead of mail.js.coffee for ex.  how do I force it to use the action I created.  Everything works when I put everything in the show action of my controller and show.js.coffee but not the mail action and mail.js.coffee etc.

This is my blast partial

```
<td><% if can? :create, Blast%><%= link_to "Mail",blast,:action => :mail  :confirm => "Are you sure?",:remote => true%><%end%></td>
```

This is the method in controller

```
def mail
  @customers = Customer.all
  @mailcustomers = Customer.where(:opted_out => false)
  @blast = Blast.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is in my mail.js.coffee file

```
 <% @mailcustomers.each do |f|%>
   <% BlastMailer.mail_blast(f,@blast).deliver %>
 <%end%>
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :blasts do
  collection {  post :mail  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. This is the line that worked.

```
<td>
  <% if can? :create, Blast%>
    <%= link_to "Mail", {:action => :mail, :id=>blast.id}, :method => :post,:confirm => "Are you sure?",:remote => true%>
  <%end%>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

(**Edit:** In my original answer, I balked at the use of ERB in a `.js.coffee` file. But on further investigation, it turns out that Rails 3.1 allows this in the special case where the JS is being served in response to a `:remote => true` form action.)

I think your problem is the

```
:action => :mail  :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

Try putting a comma after `:mail`.

Comment: Rails interprets ruby code within js.coffee files.  There is no longer a need for the erb extension. I figured out what I needed to do.  This is the line that worked. <td><% if can? :create, Blast%><%= link_to "Mail", {:action => :mail, :id=>blast.id}, :method => :post,:confirm => "Are you sure?",:remote => true%><%end%></td>

Comment: As you can see I fixed it using the line in my above comment